# Linux pointing to wrong version of Mahout

Tags: linux, path, permissions, version, mahout

I have an issue where I'm attempting to use Mahout 0.7 but Linux defaults to using Mahout 0.9.

I have mahout 0.7 at the following location: /home/cloudera/mahout-distribution-0.7

And I've updated my /etc/profile paths with the following:

```
export MAHOUT_HOME=/home/cloudera/mahout-distribution-0.7
export PATH=$MAHOUT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$MAHOUT_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
```

But when I run the "mahout" command it points to a different location at /usr/bin/mahout instead (which is mahout 0.9), and the "which mahout" points to that same location:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ which mahout
/usr/bin/mahout
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

How can I make it so that the "mahout" command will use version 0.7 instead of 0.9?

Comment: after you added the `export` lines in `/etc/profile` did you reload your terminal/console?

Comment: You probably should ask on linux-stackoverflow.  Is the `/usr/bin/mahout` a symbolic link which  you can change?